# Why Pylint says numpy.random does not have 'normal' member since it does?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

[image]

This code can run but got a error notation from vscode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pylint is a static checker but NumPy does dynamic imports of sub-modules such as `random`.
This is the relevant part of the `numpy/__init__.py`:

```
from . import random
# skipped lines
__all__.extend(['linalg', 'fft', 'random', 'ctypeslib', 'ma'])
```

In `numpy/random.__init__.py` you can find this line:

```
from .info import __doc__, __all__
```

Following this track further `numpy/random/info.py` contains:

```
__all__ = [
    # skipped lines
    'normal',
    # skipped lines
]
```

The `__init__.py` is executed during the first import of `numpy`.
The list `__all__` contains the names that `numpy` exposes.
This list is extended at run time and hence, cannot really statically be check by PyLint.

There are [different ways to turn the check of NumPy members off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553551/how-do-i-get-pylint-to-recognize-numpy-members).