# Scipy function not recognized (expit)

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, python-import, pylint

I wanted to use the expit-function from scipy in VSCode. I imported scipy.special, but everytime I want to use expit I get the following error:

"[pylint] E1101:Module 'scipy.special' has no 'expit' member"

Other scipy.special functions like scipy.special.airy work, however.

I'm using python 3.6.5 and scipy 1.1.0. Reinstalling scipy did not help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** 
I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39500741/10461550) answer, recommending to whitelist numpy for linting, the same should work for scipy.

I am having a similar issue with the function `scipy.special.j1` right now. 
Pylint complains saying

```
Module 'scipy.special' has no 'j1' member; maybe 'jv'?
```

The weird thing is that even though pylint apparently can't find the function, the following code works:

```
>>> from scipy.special import j1
>>> print(j1(2))
0.5767248077568734
```

I think this might be the exact same problem you have. Did you solve it yet? I'd love to get a solution or workaround for this.