# E1101:Module 'turtle' has no 'forward' member

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, turtle-graphics, pylint

I'm new to programming and I downloaded Python and got it running in Visual Studio Code. I was messing around with the turtle module and its functions.

The functions themselves work but `pylint` marks it as an error and says that there isn't a "member" like what I coded.

How would I go about fixing this error? (I don't want to set it to "ignore" the issue but rather recognize that the code I'm typing in is valid and comes from the turtle module)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PyLint to recognize numpy members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553551/how-do-i-get-pylint-to-recognize-numpy-members)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The turtle module exposes two interfaces, a *functional* one and an *object-oriented* one. The functional interface is derived programatically from the object-oriented interface at load time, so static analysis tools can't see it, thus your `pylint` error. Instead of the functional interface:

```
import turtle

turtle.forward(100)

turtle.mainloop()
```

For which `pylint` generates `no-member`, try using the object-oriented interface:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()

turtle.forward(100)

screen.mainloop()
```

This particular `import` for turtle blocks out the functional interface and I recommend it as folks often run into bugs by mixing both the OOP and functional interaces.

Comment: This was super helpful. Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

The functions mentioned are generated by code. PyLint only does static analysis.

I have written an astroid brain (plugin) to help the Python parser used by PyLint to add these functions.

Find the location where you have installed PyLint (directory ends with `Lib\site-packages\pylint` or `Lib/site-packages/pylint`.

Next to `pylint` is a directory `astroid`.

In the directory `Lib\site-packages\astroid\brain` or `Lib/site-packages/astroid/brain` create a file `brain_turtle.py` with the content:

```python
import astroid

def register(linter):
  pass

def transform():
  import turtle
  def _make_global_funcs(functions, cls):
    funcs = []
    for methodname in functions:
      method = getattr(cls, methodname)
      paramslist, argslist = turtle.getmethparlist(method)
      if paramslist == "": continue
      funcs.append(f"def {methodname}{paramslist}: return")
    return funcs
  funcs = []
  funcs.extend(_make_global_funcs(turtle._tg_screen_functions, turtle._Screen))
  funcs.extend(_make_global_funcs(turtle._tg_turtle_functions, turtle.Turtle))
  return astroid.parse('\n'.join(funcs))

astroid.register_module_extender(astroid.MANAGER, "turtle", transform)
```

Depending on the IDE integration of PyLint you might need to restart the IDE.

I have also created an [astroid issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid/issues/849) to add this brain to the next update of PyLint (Astroid)

You can also use this file with the `--load-plugins` command line option of `pylint`. See the [PyLint documentation for IDE integration](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/ide-integration.html). The used file needs to be on your `PYTHONPATH`