# Pylint with pytorch: Is there a way to tell pylint to look for module in different place?

Tags: python, import, pytorch, pylint

I am using `pytorch` and `pylint` does not recognize few functions for ex: `torch.stack` however, if I do `import torch._C as torch` it seems to work fine.

If I do above, actual modules that exist inside `torch` package like `torch.cuda` or `torch.nn` need to imported individually as simply doing `torch.cuda` would point to `torch._C.cuda` and hence won't work.

Is there a way to tell `pylint` to look at both `torch` and `torch._C` when I do `import torch` or even whenever it sees torch? I don't think I would use `torch` to reference any other thing in my code.

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution. I tried adding `--extension-pkg-whitelist=torch` to my `pylintrc` file, as an adaptation of the solution from <https://stackoverflow.com/q/20553551/1236650>, but I'm still getting the `E1101: Module 'torch' has no 'stack' member (no-member)` errors.

Comment: Yes I tried that too, it doesnot work.

Answer (score 2):

A solution for now is to add `torch` to `generated-members`:

```
pylint --generated-members="torch.*" ...
```

or in `pylintrc` under the `[TYPECHECK]` section:

```
generated-members=torch.*
```

I found this solution in a [reply](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/701#issuecomment-378048755) to the github discussion of the pytorch issue [[Minor Bug] Pylint E1101 Module 'torch' has no 'from_numpy' member #701](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/701). Less satisfying than whitelisting, because I guess it won't catch if you reference something that actually isn't a member, but it's the best solution I've come across so far.