# Module 'numpy' has no 'array' member

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pylint

**SOLVED**

I am having this error which is not resolved.

I have already **installed numpy completely** still having this error.

*Info: I am using Visual Studio Code.

Error:

```
Module 'numpy' has no 'array' member pylint(no-member) [3,5]
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)])
print(a)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you name your python code `numpy.py` by chance?

Comment: @CoryKramer No. I named it Numpy.py. Capital 'N'.

Comment: Change the name of your `.py`

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553551/how-do-i-get-pylint-to-recognize-numpy-members solve your problem?

Comment: @CoryKramer I changed the name of file and **it worked**. **Thanks a lot**

Comment: Voting to close this as a typo/can't be reproduced.